# Looping through the data object and Mapping Header to values in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I have a question on how to use this data to map the headers to it's corresponding values and put that on the UI

**This is how the data is structured:**

```html
{
  "data": {
    "details": [
      {     
        "address_line_1": "C O Cwtsatotravel",
        "address_line_2": "Not Available",
        "city_name": "Arlington",
        "state_name": "-",
        "country_name": "Japan",
        "postal_code": "22203",
        "phone_number": "7638527755",        
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**This is what I am trying to do in react**

```html
  const profile_info = data?.details;
  
    const profileHeaders = [
    'Address1',
    'Address2'
    'City',
    'State',
    'Postal Code',
    'Country',
    'Phone',
  ];
  
  return (
    <Grid
      id="top-card"
      className={classes.mainContainer}
      container
      style={{
        marginBottom: '4px',
      }}
    >
      {/* <Grid item md={11} lg={11} id="item-card"> */}
      <Grid container item>
        <Typography variant="subtitle1">
          {profile_info.agency_name}
        </Typography>
      </Grid>

      <Grid
        container
        style={{
          backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
        }}
      >
        {profileHeaders.map((v) => (
          <Grid
            item
            style={{
              padding: '0px 4px',
            }}
          >
            <Typography className={classes.profileData} gutterBottom={true}>
              {v}
            </Typography>
            <Typography className={classes.profileData}>
              {' '}
              {profile_info[v]}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
```

When I do this, it's getting me all blank values on the UI for the headers

Please help, thank you !

Comment: your variable `data` is the same `data` you structured?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode your headers using **the same** [as in data] **keys**:

```
const headers = {
    "address_line_1": "Address1",
    "address_line_2": "Address2",
    "city_name": "City",
```

later, you can list it

```
Object.entries(headers).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(`${key}: ${value}`));
```

`console.log(data)` to see its structure and use `const` to 'alias' iterable (object with props or array) element:

```
// choose the right data source - depends on what logged out
// console.log(data);
// if(data) console.log(data.details); //... step by step

// const profile_info = data?.details;
// const profile_info = data?.data.details;
const profile_info = data?.details[0]; // object in array here
```

render values from both `headers` and `profile_info`

```
Object.entries(headers).forEach(([key, value]) => (
 <Grid
    key={key}
    item
    style={{
      padding: '0px 4px',
    }}
  >
    <Typography className={classes.profileData} gutterBottom={true}>
      {value}
    </Typography>
    <Typography className={classes.profileData}>
      {' ??? use css instead! '}
      {profile_info[key]}
    </Typography>
  </Grid>
```

or you can do the same using `.map` (you can use `index` if required)

```
  Object.keys(headers).map((key, idx) => (
    <Element key={key}>
       <Name title={headers[key]} />
       <Value data={profile_info[key]} />
```

Comment: Really appreciate such a detailed response, will certainly try it out and let you know .. thanks again ..

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked the way I wanted it exactly :) Marked the solution as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

There is some crucial erros on your code:

1. `const profile_info = data?.details;`

Your details are stored on property `data.data.details`, not `data.details`
So fix this, first:

```
const profile_info = data?.data.details;
```

2. The items in ProfileHeaders are not mapped like properties in profile_info: you have a `profile_info['address_line_1']`, but not `profile_info['Address1']`, wich is what you are trying to do in your component.

To make this work the way you want, you should map title and property correctly.

```
const profileHeaders = [
    {
        title: "Address1",
        property:  "address_line_1"
    },
    {
        title: "Address2",
        property:  "address_line_2"
    },
    // map all other properties like above.
]
```

then you can go for that:

```
   {profileHeaders.map((v) => (
      <Grid
        item
        style={{
          padding: '0px 4px',
        }}
      >
        <Typography className={classes.profileData} gutterBottom={true}>
          {v.title}
        </Typography>
        <Typography className={classes.profileData}>
          {' '}
          {profile_info[v.property]}
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
    ))}
```

I am not checking if profile_info is undefined, but you must do it in your component to avoid errors.

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate that. I will try it out and post another comment